# Trigger animation when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-transitions

Is there any chance of making these animations I've seen on this tutorial http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/getting-animations-trigger-right-time work for elements without an image (a row of text blocks for example)? Everything works fine but once I remove the image the effect stops working. Not sure if I made myself clear. Thank you!

```
< script >
if (Modernizr.csstransitions) {
    function preloadImages(imgs, callback) {
        var cache = [],
            imgsTotal = imgs.length,
            imgsLoaded = 0;

        $(imgs).each(function (i, img) {
            var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
            cacheImage.onload = function () {
                if (++imgsLoaded == imgsTotal) callback();
            };
            cacheImage.src = $(img).attr('src');
            cache.push(cacheImage);
        });
    };
    $.fn.trans = function () {
        var t = arguments[0],
            d = arguments[1] || '';
        if (t) {
            $.each(this, function (i, e) {
                $(['-webkit-', '-moz-', '-o-', '-ms-', '']).each(function (i, p) {
                    $(e).css(p + 'transition' + d, t);
                });
            });
        }
    };

    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="animations.css" />');

    $(function () {
        //preload images contained within elements that need to animate
        preloadImages($('.services img, .featured img'), function () {
            $('.services, .featured').appear({
                once: true,
                forEachVisible: function (i, e) {
                    $(e).data('delay', i);
                },
                appear: function () {
                    var delay = 150,
                        stagger = 800,
                        sequential_delay = stagger * parseInt($(this).data('delay')) || 0;

                    $(this).children().each(function (i, e) {
                        $(e).trans(i * delay + sequential_delay + 'ms', '-delay');
                    });
                    $(this).removeClass('animationBegin');
                }
            });
        });
    });
} < /script>
```

Comment: Can you post some of the code that **you** have tried to get this working?

Comment: It exactly the same as in the tutorial. Then I tried to remove all the imgs and keep the text blocks and it didn't work.
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the article and the [working demo](http://www.netmagazine.com/files/tutorials/demos/2013/01/getting-css-animations-to-trigger-at-the-right-time/demo/demo.html) aren't exactly in sync.

I managed to get the demo working in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/BXXAK/3/)

A couple things to note:

- You *may* need to use the modified version of appear as in the fiddle.  [Located here](http://www.3magine.com/wp-content/themes/3magine/js/jquery.appear-1.1.1.modified.js)
- jQuery Appear has some logic that **must** relied on `$(window).load`, so the initialization logic has to run outside of a ready handler or trigger `load`.
- The demo's loading animations were triggered when all pending images finished pre-loading

With code copied directly from the original demo and initializing everything outside a ready block, getting it to work without images was basically a matter of getting rid of the preload callback:

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/BXXAK/5/)</kbd>

Code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.services, .featured').appear({
        once: true,
        forEachVisible: function (i, e) {
            console.log('adding delay: ' + i);
            $(e).data('delay', i);
        },
        appear: function () {
            var delay = 150,
                stagger = 800,
                sequential_delay = stagger * parseInt($(this).data('delay'), 10) || 0;

            $(this).children().each(function (i, e) {
                $(e).trans(i * delay + sequential_delay + 'ms', '-delay');
            });
            $(this).removeClass('animationBegin');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it kind of over complicates things. Try this i have done some amazing things using this. He provides the style sheet and the basic JS for scrolling animations.

http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/scrolling.html

Comment: Not a problem at all. It has speed up all of my animation development for the last few months after i found it. If you find this to be successful for your project please mark my answer as answered! Cheers

Comment: Sure I'll do that no problem ;)

Comment: Well actually I've just managed to make it work but it's not quite what I wanted as for each element I want to animate they must have a different ID. So for example if I want two elements sliding from right to left both need a different ID otherwise it won't work. On my example u just need one ID for as many elements as I need. But unfortunately it doesn't work on elements without an image :(
But anyways thanks a lot for trying to help me.

Comment: Can you post some code examples i might still be able to help get exactly what you want done. Try using a class instead of an ID for the 2 elements JS is kinda weird when you try to call an ID twice on a page. Either that or in JS call the 2 IDs on the same function 2 ID example right from that site 

     $(window).scroll(function() {
  $('**#animatedElement1, #animatedElement2**').each(function(){
  var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

  var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
   if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
    $(this).addClass("slideUp");
   }
  });
 });

Comment: Yeah, that solution works ok but since this is a custom theme I'm creating I need to make it easy for the user to customize it. So imagine the user have let's say 20 different elements with the same animation therefore the user would have to call them 20 times in the JS such as animatedElement1, animatedElement2, animatedElement3 ... animatedElement20. With my example above the user wouldn't even need to change anything in the JS. The only problem with my example is that it only works with elements that contain images. Thanks anyways very appreciated.